# Jquery sort table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such html table structure:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspasing="0" class="tablesorter zebra" id="articles-table">

    <tbody>...etc standart stuff...
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    then i have 
    <tr id="123">
    <td>
    <td>
    </td>
    </td>
    <tr>
    ...
    </table>
```

I need to sort via my float number, which is in second div only! in tr with id = 123, this is important... Also all solutions i see in web are to huge... I just need simple sort second td in some tr with specific id... How can i solve it?

I tried tablesorter.com. but it is not my... Can't customize it only for some tr... Also i need it to be sorter if document is loaded.

Comment: @Adrian i tried tablesorter.com

Answer (score 1):

I would highly advise looking into the jquery library datatables. It basically does everything you would ever need to with tables for you. You can find more information here:

http://datatables.net/

Comment: no, need own script, only own, witch i will be able to customize

Comment: @PavelBY What do you mean? The entire library is specifically made for custom behavior. What about it is not customizable? If you do not want to use that library, then no one is going to write the code to sort your table for you. sorry.

Comment: some people could write, will wait... not all peoples are so miser-like

Comment: i prefer i i have all writen by myself, by friend, etc... lib's in the end of trouble

Comment: People would be happy to help you if you had any sort of attempt in the question.

Comment: How could i invent car, if i don't know where to search at all? I simple didn't know how to do search in jquery... Is it cause for reproach?

Comment: did you minus me? If yes: thank's a lot, i will never could ask from this acc anymore

Comment: reopened question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376751/sort-table-with-jquery-after-some-tr with my try'ings

Answer (score 1):

check out tablesorter.com plugin

Comment: I tried tablesorter.com. but it is not my... Can't customize it only for some tr... Also i need it to be sorter if document is loaded. Also i have some tr with colspan on all width... So when i try to sort some part of table it give's me abracadabra