# Sort table with jquery after some tr

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable

I have such html table structure:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspasing="0" class="tablesorter zebra" id="articles-table">

    <tbody>...etc standart stuff...
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    then i have 
    <tr id="123123">
    <td colspan="7">
     Analogs
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="prcol">
    <td>
    <td>
</td>
</td>
<tr>
...
</table>
```

I tried such script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var table = $('table');
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#prcol')
    .each(function(){        
        var th = $(this),
            thIndex = th.index(),
            inverse = false;        
        th.click(function(){            
            table.find('td').filter(function(){                
                return $(this).index() === thIndex;                
            }).sortElements(function(a, b){                
                return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                    inverse ? -1 : 1
                    : inverse ? 1 : -1;                
            }, function(){
                return this.parentNode; 
            });
            inverse = !inverse;                
        });            
    });
  });
});
```

But main trouble is that it is sorting all ... But i need only that, which go after my tr with `id 123123` and sort when page is loaded...

I need to sort via my float number, which is in second div only! in tr with id = 123, this is important... Also all solutions i see in web are to huge... I just need simple sort second td in some tr with specific id... How can i solve it?

I tried tablesorter.com. but it is not my... Can't customize it only for some tr... Also i need it to be sorter if document is loaded.

**Also** try#2 here:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/GuRxj/)

with first row are troubles yet...

Comment: check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990641/jquery-tablesorter-sort-only-certain-rows-columns

Comment: oops sorry if it doesn't help.. thought it does the similar thing..

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see an example of what a starting table looks like, and what the sorted table should look like.

Comment: @slashingweapon see fiddle... I just need to sort via price (цена) td's

Comment: @slashingweapon so according to jsfiddle first in tbody.analogs_Art must be tr with price 3.36, then 3.62, 3.99, and 6.14 in top... other without text in td price at the bottom (question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387394/jquery-set-tr-with-empty-td-lower-than-with-text-in-td)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you wanted from your English, but here is what I came up with:

1. Find all tables.
2. For each table:

   1. Find the header cell marked with the class `prcol`.  That is the column we want to sort by.
   2. Find all of the `tbody` tags in the table marked with the `sortable` class.
   3. For each sortable body:

      1. Sort the rows according to the float value of the sortable cell
      2. Replace the old rows with the sorted rows

To make this work, I put the following into jQuery's document ready event:

```
$("thead .prcol").each(function(thIdx, sortElem) {
    // find our column index
    var index = $.inArray(sortElem, $(sortElem).closest('tr').children());
    var colSelector = "td:eq(_n_)".replace('_n_', index);

    $(sortElem).closest('table').children('tbody.sortable').each(function(tbIdx) {
        var rows = $(this).children('tr');
        rows.sort(function(left, right) {
            var leftText = $(colSelector, left).text();
            var rightText = $(colSelector, right).text();
            var leftValue = parseFloat(leftText) || 10000;
            var rightValue = parseFloat(rightText) || 10000;
            return  leftValue - rightValue;
        });
        $(this).html(rows);
    });
});​
```

I **[made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashingweapon/6ggR3/)** that shows the code at work.  I simplified the table a lot to make it easier to see what is happening, and I made the third table body unsorted.

Comment: hm, not so exactly: i have one table with one thead, and two tbody, for second tbody i need to do sorting, not for thead or anything else... just for tr's in tbody with class art...

Comment: That's exactly what this code will do.  Just add the `sortable` class to the body you want to be sortable.