# Jquery set tr with empty td lower than with text in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html, and jquery for sorting my table (also there is non-standart sorting (with multi-tbody)).

My code could be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/GuRxj/

As you can see there, td with prices (on russian Цена) are sorted ascending (but tech-as not!? why? (it a question too))... But as you see, i need to send this tr's with prices to top of this tbody (now there are in the bottom), while empty-price-tr send to bottom...
How to do this?

part of js:

```
$('.prcol').click(function(e) {
      var $sort = this;
      var $table = $('#articles-table');
      var $rows = $('tbody.analogs_art > tr',$table);
      $rows.sort(function(a, b){
          var keyA = $('td:eq(3)',a).text();
          var keyB = $('td:eq(3)',b).text();
            if (keyA.length > 0 && keyB.length > 0)
            {
              if($($sort).hasClass('asc')){
                  console.log("bbb");
                  return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
              } else {
                console.log(keyA+"-"+keyB);
                  return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
              }
            }
      });
      $.each($rows, function(index, row){
        //console.log(row);
        $table.append(row);
        //$("table.123").append(row);
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: `var $sort = this;` confuses people. If a variable is prefixed with `$` people expect it to contain a jQuery object.

Comment: @ThiefMaster i take it from here: http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/sort-items-alphabetically-using-jquery/

Comment: You shouldn't just copy&paste potentially bad code...

Comment: @ThiefMaster  give a better advise here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376751/sort-table-with-jquery-after-some-tr   yet i didn't found good solution, without using libs!

Comment: @ThiefMaster write good one, but don't give empty advises

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GuRxj/ ?? working? `:)` @ThiefMaster is bang on the $$ money there `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit is working fine! Just click on Цена and see... sorted as i need (only tr's in tbody.art)

Comment: @Tats_innit but is sorted so, that there are empty tr between them... i need to send this tr's with clear price td's to bottom

Comment: @PavelBY Cooleos `:)~ will take a look.

Comment: @Tats_innit didn't understand you... Who is Cooleos `:)~ ?

Comment: @PavelBY Urban lingo bruv - cool - i will take a loo. (hence 'Cool == Cooleos') `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/RwW9q/3/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/tcZNH/

Rest code should be clear to understand,

Надеюсь, что это FIDS ваши потребности `:)` (hope it fits your need,)

**Code**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var table = $('table');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.prcol').click(function(e) {
            var $sort = this;
            var $table = $('#articles-table');
            var $rows = $('tbody.analogs_art > tr', $table);
            $rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                var keyA = $('td:eq(3)', a).text().toUpperCase();;
                var keyB = $('td:eq(3)', b).text().toUpperCase();;

                if (keyA.length > 0 && isNaN(parseFloat($('td:eq(3)', b).text()))) return Ascending(keyA, keyB);
            });
            $.each($rows, function(index, row) {
                //console.log(row);
                $table.append(row);
                //$("table.123").append(row);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});

function Ascending(a, b) {
    if (a > b) return -1;
    if (a < b) return 1;
    return 0;
}​
```

Comment: maybe fits :D but why it doesn't sort? i click... and nothing ?

Comment: @PavelBY http://jsfiddle.net/RwW9q/3/ you are clicking on **Цена** on the header right? sorting fine for me `:)` I am on mac air - Lion O/S.

Comment: lol @PavelBY `:))` MAGIC indeed, Nice so it works in chrome yay, not sure man, check again or put `debugger` keyword and debug it in ff. but it should work, In morning I tested in ff, chrome and others as well.

Comment: @PavelBY lol and works in safari, there is something wrong in ff `:)` re-install or raise a bug in firefox site `:)` **Glad** it works though.

Comment: hm, how about opera and ie... there are as ff... something in code? have you any ideas why?

Comment: @PavelBY `:)` good that chrome works; I tested in my FF in the morning and it is working on both, no idea why at your end it works in chrome but not ff. usually chrome and ff complement each other well. Any DOM errors?

Comment: No. Also how to do it so, that if document loaded, it in automaticaly sort? becouse i done it via var $sort = $('.prcol');  and deleting click event... but maybe it is bad idea?

Comment: @PavelBY **like this** http://jsfiddle.net/tcZNH/ `:)` now accept my answer man lol i.e. pass is as argument cut it down to anther function. This will help. `B-)`

Comment: @PavelBY lol okies! `:)` hope rest will help and new demo will show you how to do it on load, see you around.

Comment: @PavelBY Glad it helped `:)` +1 to you as well!

Comment: one more question.... it have bugs, why for BOSCH
Воздушный фильтр
1 457 429 870
подробнее аналоги  7.18 
it is in bottom? http://jsfiddle.net/hGCgX/2/

Comment: @PavelBY I noticed that in morning **because** your code jumps first row everytime. Do you want me to fix this as well `:)` ? or you got this?

Comment: would be nice... becouse now i have a lot of work of doing my math homework... but job is job... i haven't time for this now, if you could done it, i will be happy :D

Comment: @PavelBY Cool, I will sleep soon, read your code and I reckon the issue I found was that you have 2 `tbody` and then you have one `tbody` with different id and different set or `tr` **also** if I may recommend use TableSorter plugin - it will make you like so much easier `:)` http://tablesorter.com/docs/ hope this helps.

Comment: yes... you can say that i'm an idiot) but i tested in on other machine... it run's well only on webkit browsers... please test it)

Comment: @PavelBY Cool man, `:)` no probs, I will take a look, I am bit crazy busy at the moment will look into in few hours. `:)`

Comment: also how to do it using tablesorter?

Comment: Here you go table sorter **Demo** `:)` @PavelBY http://jsfiddle.net/ScpSz/ click on the header for sorting, and right click and see the code being - add the plugin src to your page. THis will help & its much better and easy to use.

Comment: this mo is better http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-multiple-tbodies.html